# MIPS Scoreboarding Store Instruction Destination Register

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

When outlining a scoreboard for MIPS, say we have a SW instruction: SW $6, 0($5)
in the scoreboard, is Fi (destination) register considered $6 or $5?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the correct answer, both $6 and $5 in this case would both be considered sources and therefore be put in Fj and Fk